# How to make Python automatically resize wallpaper(set using python) to fit the desktop screen?

Tags: python, python-3.x

While setting an image as wallpaper using python, the image indeed becomes the wallpaper but doesn't fit the desktop screen. My code is below:

```
import ctypes,os
import win32con

image_file = 'C:/Users/aa/Desktop/wlp/RR14.jpg'                 

SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20

user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True)

user32.SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER,0,os.path.abspath(image_file),0)
```

What change should I make so that no matter what the image dimensions, it fits the desktop screen?
I'm new to python and would be really grateful for help!